# How to use token_get_all to find all T_INLINE_HTML?

Tags: php, html, token

I recently heard about a function called `token_get_all` and I want to find out how to get all of the T_INLINE_HTML out of a php file containing PHP code and HTML. For example, a file like this:

```
<?php
echo "This is my PHP code";
?>
<html>
<p>Hello, this is the HTML code I want from token_get_all!</p>
</html>
```

I was attempting to use:

```
$tokens = token_get_all($filecontents);
$html = $tokens(T_INLINE_HTML);
```

but that didn't work. How might I do this?

Answer (score 4):

The following code will filter out the tokens of a file which and leave you with only inline HTML ones:

```
$tokens = token_get_all($filecontents);
$tokens = array_filter($tokens, function($token)
{
   return $token[0] == T_INLINE_HTML;
});
```

Comment: Yay for anonymous functions! Will need PHP
 >= 5.3, though